# Notepad++ next line after auto completed brackets/tags without end-key or overtyping the autoinserted

Tags: notepad++

When notepad++ autocomplets brackets/tags I always have to hit <kbd>END</kbd> or overtype the auto inserted characters in order to get to the next line.

Is there a more handy way of going into the next line:  **like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> in some IDEs?**

typing `<p>abc`

**results in:** *(with autocomplete)*

`<p>abc|</p>`

But the cursor **`|`** is *before* the closing tag. Is the combination <kbd>END</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> the only way to go to the next line, beside (over)typing the whole closing tag?

Comment: The [Notepad# plugin](https://github.com/MarcSaenz/NotepadSharp) does many things including "Close last open tag" triggered by `Ctrl+`.  You may replace the tag completion by this one, and to avoid pressing Enter you could add a AutoHotKey macro for `Ctrl+`.  Does this sound interesting?

Comment: I cannot install this plugin as is. There is no dll. and no instructions at all. And its not in the npp plugin list so I would have to install it after every update of npp. So although it sounds good, it's doesn't really suit my requirements. Thanks anyway, sir!

Comment: Is the problem that you prefer "CTRL+Return" rather than "End+Return"?

Comment: ctrl+return is a **1-hit**-combination. End+Return is a **2 hit**-combination that takes way more time and is less fluent, also i have to leave my finger position to press end, then return and that takes additional time. try it out. with n++. you'll see what i mean. i'd prefer **any** 1-stroke-combination that does not force me to leave my default hand positions and thererfor costs me around 1-2 seconds just to get to a new line after closing an html tag. that sums up and annoys a lot.

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third-party product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To map in Notepad++ the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to
<kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
you could use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad++
Control & Enter::Send, {End}{Enter}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: Better than nothing, although I wish we could do this nativeley.